# Clingo: How to do "If p causes UNSAT then q."

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

In the code below

```
% Facts
a.

% Rules
-a :- a, not not p.
```

Adding the fact `p.` to the above would cause it to be UNSAT. Is there a way in clingo to add a rule to show this? Something like

```
q :- Assuming p causes UNSAT.
```

Solutions like adding the rule

```
{p; q} = 1.
```

Wouldn't work. It would give `q.` in the answer set if `p.` causes UNSAT, as I'd want. But, it would give `p.` and `q.` as answer sets when `p.` doesn't cause UNSAT. In the case of `p.` not causing UNSAT I wouldn't want `q.` in the answer set.

I'd like to be able to check whether certain facts causes a certain complex condition to not hold. For example, suppose one part of a problem requires you to check that a graph does NOT contain a Hamiltonian cycle. A program that finds Hamiltonian cycles would return UNSAT if the graph satisfies the condition, but I wouldn't want the program to end, since there would be other calculations to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably treat it as an optimisation problem. So something that would normally be a constraint is turned into a special predicate which you then seek to minimise. Basically you have something of the form:

```
 err(err1) :- some-bad-condition.
 err(err2) :- some-other-bad-condition.

 #minimize{ 1,XXX: err(XXX) }.
```

Here the `XXX` is a unique identifier for each error condition. The optimisation statement finds a model that minimises the number of `err`s.

The only caveat is that this increases the complexity of the problem; you're now solving an optimisation problem instead of a decision problem. It is a useful trick when debugging asp programs, but for large/difficult problems it may be too slow.

Comment: This does solve the example I gave, but I'd appreciate a clarification on how this would apply to the Hamiltonian cycle example in my last paragraph. From what I understand, using your method I'd have the line `err(err1) :- cycle_exists.`, but defining `cycle_exists` is equivalent to the question I asked, namely checking if a block of code (in this case a block of code which finds a Hamiltonian cycle) is satisfiable.

Comment: Can you provide a more concrete example of the overall problem you are trying to model?  Maybe you can break your program into separate programs and check their satisfiability individually? SAT/UNSAT applies to the program as a whole, so within a program you should be thinking about properties (or facts) as holding and not holding. So for the Hamiltonian cycle, instead of having a constraint that makes the program unsatisfiable if there is no cycle, you encode that if there is a cycle then these extra properties must also hold and if there is no cycle then these other properties must hold.

Comment: The following question is an example of what I want to solve. _Given a graph G. Find the minimum number of edges you need to remove from G so that it no longer contains a Hamiltonian cycle._

Comment: I think you have to look into disjunctive logic programs. It might be a NP^2 hard problem. There is way to model such things but I'm not competent enough to explain it.